# Why do divs with width as percent display as different lengths on localhost vs ElasticBeanstalk environment?

Tags: css, reactjs, localhost, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running the same code on localhost and my ElasticBeanstalk server where a few classes use percentages as width. [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage) for percentage say that percentages are used

> to define a size as relative to an element's parent object.

Yet throughout the DOM tree, width values end up being off by .005 (see pictures). My assumption is that the app's root size is slightly different causing the slight differences when calculating percent. As these small values add up, they can make things appear to be shifted from their desired position.

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent this?

One of the classes as an example:

```
.student-profile-question-preview {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 30%;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

[Picture 1 for reference - localhost is on left and EB environment is on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxajs.png)

[Picture 2 for reference - you can clearly see the left is bigger but the width value is the same due to rounding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBul7.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the viewport width is the same on those 2 images?

Comment: I shortened them in one window, then dragged the second tab out just to make sure. I again tried to collapse both windows to be the smallest they could be and compared their size. Thanks for asking, this is my first question on SO

Comment: Since both DOM box models are saying 350 width, it looks like you're looking at two sites with different zooms set -- Chrome can do this easily. 'View -> Actual Size' on both sites to determine you're viewing at actual sizes.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That was the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Coll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5818406/coll) stated,

> it looks like you're looking at two sites with different zooms set -- Chrome can do this easily. 'View -> Actual Size' on both sites to determine you're viewing at actual sizes.

Thanks for the help - I never knew the zoom could be toggled like that between tabs.